# Is there hitTest:(CGPoint) in CAShapeLayer?

Tags: iphone, ipad, calayer

I have a multiple CAShapeLayers in a view and I'd like to drag it.(shape are irregular) Please give some suggestions for doing it.

Comment: As CAShapeLayer inherits from CALayer, you should be able to grab them with hitTest.

Comment: Hi Alec, I'm unable to detect the test, what i'm doing is while touching the CAShapelayer there no event fired at touchBegans: withEvent: in subclass of CAshapelayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CALayer` and its subclasses are not part of the responder chain, and they do not descend from `UIResponder`. Therefore, `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, etc. will never be called on any `CALayer` subclass. You need to detect the touch on one of the hosting `UIView`s in the layer hierarchy. Then, you use `hitTest:` in the touch handlers to detect which layer was touched.

It will be easier on you if you create a `UIView` subclass with a `CAShapeLayer` as its backing layer like this:

```
@implementation MyShapeView

- (CALayer *)layerClass {
  return [CAShapeLayer class];
}

@end
```

Then, add instances of your custom view as subviews to your main view. After that, you can use the `UIResponder` methods or, even better, a `UIGestureRecognizer` to handle the dragging. I highly recommend using gesture recognizers if you can target iOS 3.2 or higher. They make event handling much simpler.